# how to set up weblogic managed server in eclipse for debugging an application

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have an admin server and a managed server in my weblogic, and I have added the admin server(listening on 7001) in eclipse using weblogic tools suite and I can debug my applications which are on admin server. So now my question is I want to add the other managed server(listening on 7002) in my eclipse and want to debug the app's deployed on managed server. How can I achieve this functionality, is there a way that I can add managed server on to the servers tab in eclipse.

Comment: Add it the same way you added the admin server.

Comment: I tried that, but it complains that this same domain was used by some other server